# Can't add to ArrayList

Tags: java, applet

Been trying to add an object (coordinates of a missile) to ArrayList, but it only adds the last one. There's only one object in ArrayList.

Missile class

```
   public ArrayList<Missilies> missilies = new ArrayList<Missilies>();

  //  New missile object  ////////

 public Missilies(int x, int y){

    // missilies = new ArrayList<Missilies>();
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;

     visible=true;

 }

   public  void fire(){


    System.out.println("Fire !!!");

        missilies.add(new Missilies(x,y));
        System.out.println(" New missile added, total="+
                    +missilies.size()+"  missile    "+missilies);
 }
```

Player class.
Now it works.

```
 @Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:{

        if (lastKey == null || lastKey != e.getKeyChar()) {
            lastKey = e.getKeyChar();
            Missilies m = new Missilies(x,y);
            m.fire();
            missilies.add(m);
           System.out.println("Missilies "+missilies);


            System.out.println("keyPressed: " + lastKey);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By having the list of missiles inside the `Missilies` class, you make each missile have its own list - and the missile itself is the only thing on its list.  You need to move the declaration of the list to a different class.

Comment: correctly pointed, also you can add the same missiles instance in the list in method fire by  `missilies.add(this);`

Comment: @David Wallace It work's now. Would be better to create a different class with method fire() in it and instantiate ArrayList there?

Comment: You could also declare the missiles arraylist as static, making it a class object rather than an instance object.

Comment: @RomZes, that is what I would do, yes.  There must be some kind of object in your game that owns that list, and controls things like firing.  Don't try to give the `Missilies` class too much responsibility, if all it is supposed to do is to represent a missile.  Oh, and I don't recommend using a static field for this - I consider overuse of statics to be poor design, as it blurs the responsibilities of what each class should do.  In my experience, it can also make testing rather more difficult.

Comment: @DavidWallace That's what I'll work on. Otherwise it makes things complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the fire method or the list declaration outside the Missile class, you will get all the missile objects populated in your list